# Add Table to PdfStamper.AcroFields iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am getting started working with iTextSharp and am having trouble doing something pretty straightforward. I have a template that I am populating with PdfStamper like so

```
 PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(@"C:\temp\Template.pdf");
 PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(rdr, new System.IO.FileStream(path = @"C:\temp\Created.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
 stamper.AcroFields.SetField("softwarename", "Software");
 stamper.FormFlattening = true; 
 AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
 form.GenerateAppearances = true;
 stamper.Close();
 rdr.Close();
```

I want to be able to have a field called "grid" or something like that, and populate it with a PdfPTable with all the formatting intact (I know I can do it all in strings, but I don't want that). Is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: PDFs don't know a table form element. You can instead create a table containing a form element for each cell. Alternatively look into XFA forms. They don't fulfil your expectations either but they fail less doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDFStamper documentation says that it takes all objects allowed, so I would use a combination of objects (or lists of objects) and flags.  That way you can pass in all the info you need an manipulate it according the whatever logic you need.

The following code will place images in a grid equally across the top of the page using the PdfPTable.

Then you can use PdfTemplate and use the WriteSelectedRows method to write the contents of the PdfPTable to it.

```
        PdfPTable table;
        string inputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "input.pdf");
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "output.pdf");

List<ImageTextSharpModel> images

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(images.Count);
                    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

                    for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
                    {

                        var image = images[i];
                        try
                        {
                            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                            cell.BorderWidth = 0;
                            cell.FixedHeight = image.Height;
                            cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;                                  
                            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

                            float offset = 0;

                            var img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image.AbsolutePath);
                            img.ScaleToFit(image.Width, image.Height);

                            //Manually setting the location 
                            if (image.Alignment == iTextSharp.text.Image.RIGHT_ALIGN)
                            {
                                offset = i == 0
                                    ? (((doc.PageSize.Width/images.Count) - doc.LeftMargin) - img.ScaledWidth)
                                    : (((doc.PageSize.Width/images.Count) - doc.LeftMargin) - img.ScaledWidth) - cell.Width;
                            }
                            else if (image.Alignment == iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER)
                            {
                                if (images.Count == 1)
                                {
                                    offset = ((doc.PageSize.Width - img.ScaledWidth)/2) - doc.LeftMargin;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    offset = (((doc.PageSize.Width/images.Count) - img.ScaledWidth)/2);
                                }
                            }     

                            p.Add(new Chunk(img, offset, 0));
                            cell.AddElement(p);
                            table.AddCell(cell);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //Ignore
                        } 
                    }
;

            //add table to stamper
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new     iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inputFile);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, fs))
        {
                int PageCount = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int x = 1; x <= PageCount; x++)
                {

                    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetOverContent(x);
                    PdfTemplate tableTemplate = canvas.CreateTemplate(1500, 1300);
                    table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 1300, tableTemplate);

                }

                stamper.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think my issue is getting the table into the stamper. How do you do that?

Comment: Ah.  You use the PdfTemplate and use the WriteSelectedRows method to write your PdfPTable to the PDFTemplate.  I've added the code to my example above.